# PostgreSQL, SQL Shell(psql) psql: error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: sql, postgresql, passwords, psql

SQL shell(psql)  throws me this error when prompting pasword for user postgress    psql: error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

tried CMD
C:\Users\myuser>psql
Password for user myuser:
psql: error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

C:\Users\myuser>psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

found this 1. answer :maybe is this isue 
 pgpass.conf file needs to put it to PostgreSQL server and not with pgAdmin (client's dir)?? but cant find such file in explorer

pgAdmin 4 works just fine problem is with psql shell

im on WIN 10 ,anyone have same problem and how to solve it?

PS: i managed to work psql shell by setting pg_hba.config file to

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

for ip4 and ip6 i set trust instade md5 and relaoded Postgress service ,but when i reverted back after seting new pasword to md5  same problem and same error

psql: error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

pgAdmin 4 still works

Answer (score 1):

I've installed and uninstalled many times and I have managed to get the desired result in the picture below...

[image]

1. Install [postgres](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) without changing anything, except entering a new password and open the sql shell by entering 'psql' in your Windows search menu.
2. Inside SQL shell, keep pressing enter until it prompts you for your
   password which you created on the installer
3. Type your password here, even though it doesn't look like it is
   being keyed in and press enter once done.

It should look like...

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (12.2)

WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

4. Install pgadmin from this link [pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaGxp.jpg), enter the password from psql 
   and you should then see the following...

[image]

5. Click on the server database icon top left and add the password which you entered in psql.
6. Create a database and get the list.

   ```
   postgres=# CREATE DATABASE your_database_name OWNER postgres; #Click enter here
   CREATE DATABASE #result
   postgres=# \l #to get the below datbase list
   ```

[image]

7. Go back to pg admin, refresh the browser, and click on the server icon.

**Note:** Should you need to uninstall/re-install you will need to manually delete the folder where you have installed Postgres and pgadmin. This is even after uninstalling from system settings. For some reason, Postgres folder's don't remove entirely even though you select the option.